# Receber Json com argumentos vazios

Tags: android, json

Criei uma API para receber os dados do banco de dados via json para minha aplicação android, mas algumas colunas da minha tabela recebem nulo, gerando um argumento do json vazio que estar gerando erro em minha aplicação, gostaria de descobrir a melhor forma de tratar essa informação já que é importante saber se a variável estar ou não vazia.

ex:

```
Json: "redes_sociais":{"id":1,"telefone":"99999","whatsapp":"99999","facebook":"face","instagram":"","twiter":"","youtube":"","email":""}

Construtor da entidade no android:
public RedesItem(JSONObject rede) throws JSONException {
    this.id = rede.getLong("id");
    this.telefone = rede.getString("telefone");
    this.whatsapp = rede.getString("whatsapp");
    this.face = rede.getString("face");
    this.insta = rede.getString("insta");
    this.twiter = rede.getString("twiter");
    this.youtube = rede.getString("youtube");
    this.email = rede.getString("email");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Para verificar se existe a chave no json você pode utilizar o método `has` da classe JSONObject.

Veja a documentação [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String))

**Exemplo:**

```
 this.telefone = (rede.has("telefone")) ? rede.getString("telefone") : null;
```